# Count the total occurrences of each unique word in a flat array of multi-word elements

Tags: php, arrays, string, cpu-word, word-count

Input array:

```
$array = [
    'Mary',
    'Mary had a little',
    'a lamb',
    'Mary mary mary',
    'lady'
];
```

Desired output:

```
[
    'Mary' => 5,
    'a' => 2,
    'had' = 1,
    'little' => 1,
    'lady' => 1
]
```

Comment: You could store each word into an array with a regex then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php to count the uniques... or you could iterate over and explode on spaces..

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far

Comment: $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query4);
$json = mysqli_fetch_all ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json);

Answer (score 5):

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/771578)

```
<?php
$array=array(
0 => 'Mary',
1 => 'Mary had a little',
2 => 'a lamb',
3 => 'Mary mary mary',
4 => 'lady'
);
$data=array();
foreach($array as $sentence)
{
    //gatering words in an array by spliting the sentence on space.
    $data=  array_merge($data,explode(" ", $sentence));
}
//counting values present in array for case sensitive
$result=array_count_values($data);
print_r($result); //Result 1

//counting values present in array for case insensitive by changing each array element to lowercase
$result=array_count_values(array_map("strtolower", $data));
print_r($result); //Result 2
```

**Output:**

```
//result 1
Array
(
    [Mary] => 3
    [had] => 1
    [a] => 2
    [little] => 1
    [lamb] => 1
    [mary] => 2
    [lady] => 1
)
//result 2
Array
(
    [mary] => 5
    [had] => 1
    [a] => 2
    [little] => 1
    [lamb] => 1
    [lady] => 1
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Rizier adding explaination

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to make iterated calls of `explode()` and `array_merge()`. Just let `implode()` condense the data into a string, reduce the case, convert back to a 1-dimensional array, then count.  Easy.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4Sdut))

```
$array = [
    'Mary',
    'Mary had a little',
    'a lamb',
    'Mary mary mary',
    'lady'
];

var_export(
    array_count_values(
        explode(' ',
            strtolower(
               implode(' ', $array)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'mary' => 5,
  'had' => 1,
  'a' => 2,
  'little' => 1,
  'lamb' => 1,
  'lady' => 1,
)
```

Comment: Why can't answer scores be trusted on Stack Overflow? Because even after a superior answer is posted, the lesser answer's score continues to grow for no sound reason.